# ConfigurableMongoDbMessageStore Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.messaging.support.GenericMessage]

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, spring-integration

I am trying to use the ConfigurableMongoDbMessageStore as a message-store in my spring-integration aggregator component. For some reason the following exception is thrown:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.model.MappingInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate org.springframework.messaging.support.GenericMessage using constructor NO_CONSTRUCTOR with arguments 
    at org.springframework.data.convert.ReflectionEntityInstantiator.createInstance(ReflectionEntityInstantiator.java:67)
    at org.springframework.data.convert.ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator.createInstance(ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator.java:84)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:272)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:245)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.readValue(MappingMongoConverter.java:1491)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$MongoDbPropertyValueProvider.getPropertyValue(MappingMongoConverter.java:1389)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$AssociationAwareMongoDbPropertyValueProvider.getPropertyValue(MappingMongoConverter.java:1438)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$AssociationAwareMongoDbPropertyValueProvider.getPropertyValue(MappingMongoConverter.java:1401)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.PersistentEntityParameterValueProvider.getParameterValue(PersistentEntityParameterValueProvider.java:71)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.SpELExpressionParameterValueProvider.getParameterValue(SpELExpressionParameterValueProvider.java:49)
    at org.springframework.data.convert.ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator$EntityInstantiatorAdapter.extractInvocationArguments(ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator.java:250)
    at org.springframework.data.convert.ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator$EntityInstantiatorAdapter.createInstance(ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator.java:223)
    at org.springframework.data.convert.ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator.createInstance(ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator.java:84)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:272)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:245)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:194)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:190)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:78)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate$ReadDocumentCallback.doWith(MongoTemplate.java:3017)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.executeFindMultiInternal(MongoTemplate.java:2673)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFind(MongoTemplate.java:2404)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFind(MongoTemplate.java:2387)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.find(MongoTemplate.java:823)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.findOne(MongoTemplate.java:772)
    at org.springframework.integration.mongodb.store.ConfigurableMongoDbMessageStore.getMessageGroup(ConfigurableMongoDbMessageStore.java:115)
    at org.springframework.integration.mongodb.store.ConfigurableMongoDbMessageStore.addMessageToGroup(ConfigurableMongoDbMessageStore.java:138)
    at org.springframework.integration.aggregator.AbstractCorrelatingMessageHandler.store(AbstractCorrelatingMessageHandler.java:757)
    at org.springframework.integration.aggregator.AbstractCorrelatingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractCorrelatingMessageHandler.java:479)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:162)
    ... 83 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.messaging.support.GenericMessage]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.messaging.support.GenericMessage.<init>()
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:129)
    at org.springframework.data.convert.ReflectionEntityInstantiator.createInstance(ReflectionEntityInstantiator.java:64)
    ... 111 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.messaging.support.GenericMessage.<init>()
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3350)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2554)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:122)
    ... 112 common frames omitted
```

The bean is created and used as follows:

```
In SpringIntegrationBeans.java

    @Autowired
    private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    @Bean(name = "configurableMongoDbMessageStore")
    public ConfigurableMongoDbMessageStore configurableMongoDbMessageStore() {
        return new ConfigurableMongoDbMessageStore(mongoTemplate);
    }

In spring-integration.xml
        <int:aggregator id="myAggregator"
                        ref="testingAggregator"
                        message-store="configurableMongoDbMessageStore"/>
```

I am using the following spring-integration-mongodb package:

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-integration-mongodb</artifactId>
      <version>5.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

I found similar q&a in [Spring Integration Aggregator with MongoDbMessageStore: Failed to instantiate GenericMessage: No default constructor found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46428742/spring-integration-aggregator-with-mongodbmessagestore-failed-to-instantiate-ge) but that seems to be applicable for MongoDbMessageStore rather than ConfigurableMongoDbMessageStore

I would appreciate any help/advice.

Answer (score 0):

The mongo template needs a suitably configured converter; inject the db factory instead and the store will create an appropriate template.

```
@Autowired
private MongoDbFactory dbFactory;

@Bean(name = "configurableMongoDbMessageStore")
public ConfigurableMongoDbMessageStore configurableMongoDbMessageStore() {
    return new ConfigurableMongoDbMessageStore(dbFactory);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But that resulted in an exception saying: Caused by: org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializationFailedException: Failed to serialize object using DefaultSerializer; nested exception is java.io.NotSerializableException: com.myTestProject.model.MyTestObject.
 MyTestObject pojo contains a few private field with public getters and setters

Comment: Right, as explained in the JavaDocs, everything has to be `Serializable` to use that store. Have you tried the `MongoDbMessageStore` instead?

Comment: Ok. Yes, I tried the MongoDbMessageStore first but it could not decode/encode a field property in my pojo of type java.time.ZonedDateTime. I have added a custom converter for this to the MongoTemplate, which I am able to use with my MongoRepository dao  with no problem. But I have not found a way to use these custom converters with the MongoDbMessageStore, hence trying out the ConfigurableMongoDbMessageStore.

Comment: Do I need to implement Serializable for all objects I need to store in message-store or can I provide an ObjectMapper (jackson) or similar to the ConfigurableMongoDbMessageStore component to handle this? Please share any ConfigurableMongoDbMessageStore examples that you think can be helpful.

Comment: The `MongoDbMessageStore` has a bunch of private converters for handling Message and some of the richer headers (message history etc), but it doesn't provide any hooks for additional converters, unfortunately. The Configurable store was intended to provide the extensibility (by allowing you to inject a template). But you are on your own. You might be able to copy the `DocumentToGenericMessageConverter` from the other store; depending on your app, you may not need all the features provided by the `MessageReadingMongoConverter`.

Comment: Please open a GitHub issue and we'll see if we can make it easier to extend by adding converters.

Comment: Ok, thanks. So you mean I should try to add the DocumentToGenericMessageConverter (and more if needed) to my  ConfigurableMongoDbMessageStore? I have btw created https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/issues/2936.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. But this is an area that I am not too familiar with, my Mongo team-mate is out of town this week.

Comment: Ok, I got it. I will try it and hopefully your team-mate can assist when back. Thanks.